# Python unquote URL but retain hyperlink

Tags: python, urllib, urllib3

I have a URL written in Cyrillic. When inserting it in python, I get its encoded form:

```
link = https://dspace.udpu.edu.ua/bitstream/6789/1751/1/%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%83%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%96%20%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%20%D0%B4%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D1%96%D0%B4%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8F.pdf
```

To convert it into a hyperlink with Cyrillic characters, I have tried using urllib.parse.unquote:

```
from urllib.parse import unquote
unquoted_link = unquote(link)
```

The result for *unquoted_link* is:

[https://dspace.udpu.edu.ua/bitstream/6789/1751/1/Загальнонаукові](https://dspace.udpu.edu.ua/bitstream/6789/1751/1/%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%83%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%96) методи дослідження.pdf

I.e., I have the hyperlink only before the first space, and then it is plain text. How can I make this whole string a hyperlink, just as StackOverflow does in the first hyperlink I provided?

Comment: The problem is not with the URL, but with the rendering engine's interpretation of the string. It simply assumes that a whitespace terminates a URL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The unquoted URL is a valid hyperlink. For example, when it is placed within quotes in an HTML link, it works as expected. The issue is that in certain contexts, whitespace is treated as a terminator, for example, in various terminals.

```html
<a href="https://dspace.udpu.edu.ua/bitstream/6789/1751/1/Загальнонаукові методи дослідження.pdf">
    https://dspace.udpu.edu.ua/bitstream/6789/1751/1/Загальнонаукові методи дослідження.pdf</a>
```

Comment: I need what you stated in the last paragraph. However, this does not work. I tried it with mark_safe and format_html, but it return the same broken link that I had given in my question.

Comment: Yes, sorry. The error was only in Python terminal. Unquote had worked from the very beginning.